Argument list too long when running fuzzer coverage
I am running a fuzzer to get coverage information, using command below:
LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="/scratch/smp-fuzzer-out/default.profraw" $AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/bin/smp-fuzzer-cov /scratch/smp-fuzzer-out/inputs/*

However, the command failed because 'argument list too long'. I searched about this problem and found it's because there are too many files in a directory.
I checked /inputs and found there are more than 40000 files. Also, I tried the getconf ARG_MAX which returns 2097152. So I don't know why 40000+ inputs is not OK.
Is there some way to fix this problem? Using a for loop may not work because default.profraw should be generated one time.
